# How to plot small floating numbers properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How to plot the set of numbers like (first column is x-axis, second column is y-axis):

```
1 3.4335e-14 
2 5.8945e-28 
3 6.7462e-42 
4 5.7908e-56 
5 3.9765e-70 
6 2.2756e-84 
7 1.1162e-98 
8 4.7904e-113 
9 1.8275e-127 
10 6.2749e-142 
11 1.9586e-156 
12 5.6041e-171 
13 1.4801e-185 
14 3.6300e-200 
15 8.3091e-215 
16 1.7831e-229 
17 3.6013e-244 
18 6.8694e-259 
19 1.2414e-273
```

For now I get:

[image: plot]

And I can't figure out how to make it properly. It means no flat line from 2 to the end and correct y-axis values. I read these values from the file with:

```
x_values.append(line.split(' ')[0])
y_values.append(float(line.split(' ')[1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to switch the `yscale` to "log" scale, e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
_,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks(x)
plt.yscale("log")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2e'));
```

[image]

Comment: Looks much better, but I still need scientific notation labels on y axis.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the 'ax' subplots? In case you do not have subplots, can ou do this with plt?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar You may try converting `x` to string of the desired format manually